# Python Thrift binary type requires encoding?

Tags: python, character-encoding, binary, thrift

I'm trying to use the 'binary' Thrift data type in python to send binary data. When the actual client operation is starting (before the send actually happens), the client triggers an exception complaining about UTF coding. Does the Thrift Python library not support true binary encoding? Is this because I'm using the JSON protocol and the protocol doesn't protect itself for the binary definition. Under the hood, the Thrift 0.9.1 generates a 'binary' field as a 'string' (same for Java and C++). Is this the nature of 'binary' at this point in time?

My Thrift definition and client code snippet are:

```
-------------------- Thrift ---------------------
struct Msg {
  1:    binary      aBinary,
}

service Service {
    oneway  void    asyncMsg(   1: Msg   msg),   // Async
}

-------------------- Python ---------------------

socket = TSocket.TSocket(host, port)
transport = TTransport.TFramedTransport(socket)
protocol = TJSONProtocol.TJSONProtocol(transport)
client = Service.Client(protocol)
transport.open()

binaryData = ""
for a in range(0,255):
    binaryData += struct.pack("B",a)

print "Sending a Binary String"
client.asyncMsg(Service.Msg(aBinary = binaryData))
```

Error when running python client code ....
Error: failed to send to remote end: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 128: invalid start byte

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Using TBinaryProtocol does fix this problem, but I was hoping to use JSON encoding to allow other entities between the client and server.

Comment: This makes sense as JSON is defined to be UTF-8 through out the document. The 'binary' IDL type is not useable with JSON protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Thrift JSON transport, `binary` data are expected to be base64 encoded, with or without padding. Since base64 easily fits even into an 8-byte-character string, the problem you are facing indicates very likely a problem in the Python JSON transport.

Unfortunately, the `binary` data type still lacks some test coverage. [This is about to change](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2886).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use the TBinaryProtocol instead of JSON. JSON encoding requires all content to be UTF-8 compatible.

Comment: Disagree. Binary should work with JSON as well. "*Is string the the nature of 'binary' at this point in time?*" - Binary has been added that way, that's true. So you'll find stuff like that in the code base, yes. It should work nevertheless. If it doesn't ...

Comment: Edited "solution" into "workaround", because that's what it really is.

Comment: If JSON, by definition, is expected to encoded into UTF-8, then binary data must be encoded to a form that can be used in an assignment to type 'String', no? The JSON encoding seems to attempt an assignment and the above test fails. The test fails precisely at the first byte with the high order bit '1'.

Comment: "*The 'binary' IDL type is not useable with JSON protocol*" - Sorry, but wrong. The transport of `binary` data via JSON should work with Python exactly the same way as it works with all other languages. If it doesn't work, [there must be something broken](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT) with the Python bindings. Sad, but true.

Comment: Maybe the Python bindings are broken as 'binary' yields the same as 'string' in the generated code. Turns out to be the same for Java and C++ too. I assume those languages work?

Comment: As I already wrote above, yes. Binary has some things in common with string, mostly for historical reasons. Why it is how it is, and what reasons lead to that decision is surely worth discovering, but simply not important here. The key point is: It should work. It's that simple. If you found a bug by trying binary via JSON -  congratulations. If not, we'll find out soon enough.